# Simple imputer delete nan instead of imputation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to impute NaN values with `SimpleImputer` mean strategy but instead of imputing it, it deletes the `NaN` values, I read how to use it 
[here](https://analyticsindiamag.com/data-pre-processing-in-python/) and [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), it simply does not work with numpy array or python lists, what's wrong? and what is the solution?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.array([[2,3,6,5,4, np.nan],[2,3,6,15,4, np.nan]])

SI = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
X = SI.fit_transform(X)
print(X)
```

output

```
runfile('D:/python projects/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/python projects')
[[ 2.  3.  6.  5.  4.]
 [ 2.  3.  6. 15.  4.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values in the last column are `Nan` in your data. Hence, the imputer removes that column, because it does not know what value needs to be imputed. Please make sure you have at least one non- `Nan` value in your data for allowing imputer to work.

```
X = np.array([[2,3,6,5,4, np.nan],
              [2,3,6,15,4, np.nan], 
              [1,2,6,2,4, 1] ])

SI = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
SI.fit_transform(X)


# Output:
[[ 2.  3.  6.  5.  4.  1.]
 [ 2.  3.  6. 15.  4.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  6.  2.  4.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [239]: SI=SimpleImputer(verbose=1)                                                          
In [240]: SI.fit_transform(X)                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/impute/_base.py:403: UserWarning: Deleting features without observed values: [5]
  "observed values: %s" % missing)
Out[240]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.,  6.,  5.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  6., 15.,  4.]])
```

tweak X:

```
In [241]: X = np.array([[2,3,6,5,4, np.nan],[2,3,6,15,np.nan, 4]])                             
In [242]: SI.fit_transform(X)                                                                  
Out[242]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.,  6.,  5.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  6., 15.,  4.,  4.]])
```